# Is there a bracha on burning nossar?

Tags: blessing, korban

Nossar, the parts of a Korban that are not eaten within the allotted time, must be destroyed.

Was there a bracha on burning nossar?  If so, what is it?  If not, why not?

Comment: What about burning any other the other parts of Korbanot that were burnt? Why specifically ask about Notar?

Comment: @DoubleAA  I did not reflect on such related topics when I posted my question, but I like your expanded question.  Yet, perhaps it makes sense to start small with this topic and wait for the answer before asking larger questions.

Comment: @DoubleAA What about bringing korbanos in general? I would argue that since this is a lav hanitak le'aseh it's not the kind of thing we make a bracha on - you don't bless tashlumei keifel, for instance...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky  Not all readers are familiar with the term "lav hanitak le'aseh" - positive commandment which is attached to a prohibition.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky How do you know that we dont make a brocho on a lav hanitak le-aseh?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I'm not 100% on this, but I'm pretty sure it's talked about by burning the left overs from pesach, that there is no brachah since the origin of the mitzvah comes from the violation of nossar

Comment: The first comment of Mishne L'melech on Ma'ase Hakarbanos distills a general debate over each element of avoda having its own b'racha, only the "big" ones (which ones?) having a b'racha, or there being one b'racha applying to all the avodos of the day. This should relate to but not answer the question fully because it is only talking about kohanim in the mikdash and nosar could be burned by anyone and elsewhere (cf. עה"ה פסולי המוקדשים קנ"ו).

Answer (score 6):

In **Sefer Abudarham,**   in Shaar Hashlishi which addresses Birkat Hamitsvot,  a Teshuva of **Rabbi Yosef Ben Pelat.**  The issue is to find a criterion for blessing on a mitsva. In the Teshuva RYBP wrote that **mitsvot that come as consequence of  a sin,**   as returning the stolen object,  returning ribbit,  are exempted from beracha.

Further RYBP  [**wrote mefurash that notar has no Beracha:**](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&st=&pgnum=15) (last word of the 15th line of the right column)

> וכן שרפת נותר לא תותירו והנותר ממנו,  אלו כולן ומאי דדמי להו משום דהוו מצוה הבאה בעבירהלא מברכינן עלייהו

Later he explained the rational,  linking the issue with the known Suggia of Mitsva habaa beavera,  but I did not understand. His main proof is from the Gemara BK 94a which says that a man who bless for hafrashat challa on a dough made by wheat that he had stolen, he is not blessing but cursing.

Answer (score 5):

In *Igros Moshe*, *Kadashim*, vol. 1, #15, [toward the end](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14673&st=&pgnum=375), he says

**Yes**

on the basis of being unconvinced of a reason not to. The questioner apparently thought that one would not, and while the *t'shuva* does not mention the categorical exception to the *b'racha* requirement in @kouty's answer, he does consider and preempt a closely related concern.

[Earlier](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14673&st=&pgnum=372), he'd analyzed the purpose of the *mitzva* to burn *nosar*, and some of the ramifications thereof. In that section he entertained the idea of two (or three) subtypes of *lav hanitak la'ase*, which would operate differently. One type was a positive *mitzva* that is designed to effect a state, the accomplishment of which *de facto* negates transgression of a separate prohibition. This sounds like the Avudraham's categorical exclusion, but Rav Moshe did not believe this *mitzva* fit into that criterion.

For more, and interesting criticism of this *t'shuva*, see *Riv'vos Efrayim* 8:368.

Re the wording of the putative *b'racha*, the general pattern of "אשר קדשנו בקדושתו של אהרן וצונו..." may not fit here, at least when the burning is performed by a non *kohen*. But it might be a different *mitzva* for *kohanim* and others. (I have wondered but never found an answer to what *b'racha* a *kohen* says when he eats the *korban pesach*, for the latter reason.)

Comment: shkoyech,  I want to read the Abudarham up to the end of the Shut and afterwards the Igrot Moshe,  have you a link?

Comment: I have the Abudarham at home but not the IM

Comment: see my addition,  the Abudarham is mefurash about notar.

Comment: @kouty - I scanned the relevant part of Riv'vos Efrayim and was about to post it when I realized I have no idea what copyright it is under. If you would like to see it let me know.

Comment: just by curiosity,  he reported Abudarham?

Comment: I found in Hebrewbooks רבבות אפרים perhaps the exact reference may be sufficient.

Comment: @kouty _chelek_ 8 O.C. #368 at the end. He doesn't mention it, but he's not really concerned about the _b'racha_ as much as the fundamental obligation of the _mitzva_. On that note, I suspect when it says _sh'lishis_ in that paragraph it really means _sh'lilis_, but it happens twice, so it would be a strange typo.